# Is there a way to create a new Coinbase account for someone else (as a gift) using the API?

Tags: bitcoin, ethereum, coinbase-api

I'd like to know if there's a way to use the Coinbase API create a new Coinbase account for someone who doesn't have a Coinbase account and possibly even deposit some Bitcoin/Ethereum for them in it?

I've seen the [API docs on Authentication](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#authentication) but it seems like accessing one's own account or letting existing Coinbase access a 3rd party app.

Comment: Your question may be more suited to another StackExchange site. For questions related to Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies, please ask on the [**Bitcoin StackExchange**](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) instead. For questions *specific* to Ethereum, please ask on the [**Ethereum StackExchange**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) instead. For further information, please refer to the documentation regarding what is considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)' for StackOverflow, and what questions [**shouldn't be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I can't delete it because someone answered it but also it seems like I asked it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is to simply send the gift crypto currency to an email address.

https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#send-money

If the email address already has a coinbase account associated with it the account will simply be credited. If the email does not have a coinbase account they can easily sign up to claim the gift just by entering the password they want for their account. The account will be created using the email the gift was sent to and the password they chose after clicking the link in the email.